# Separate provisioning profile for notification extension

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, codemagic

I have problems with signing iOS app with notification extension on Codemagic CI.

I created App Id and provisioning profile with this id. App was builded and uploaded to App Store fine.

But when I added notification extension I got problems. That extension needs to have separate provisioning profile.

How it can be done? 
My app id is com.myapp
And notification extension is com.myapp.notification

I can’t add notification to existing provisioning profile - it is not listed in developer portal when I start to edit existing profile.

Should I create new provisioning profile? In this case should I create separate app id for extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need an additional provisioning profile for each extension.

And in Codemagic you can upload multiple provisioning profiles in Code Signing settings (https://docs.codemagic.io/code-signing/ios-code-signing/#setting-up-manual-code-signing)

Comment: Should I create separate App ID for extension? Otherwise how could I create additional provisioning profile?

Comment: problem solved, need to point out that I didn't have to create separate app id - it was created automatically after I created App Group and added app and notification targets in it

Comment: @moonvader I have the same problem. Do you have the documentation to create an App Group, please?